# Unreal Engine 4.25 Github version: Can't Compile C++ code

Tags: c++, github, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

I am trying to create a new C++ class from the editor, after successfully build the related class, modified the .cpp and header file. Basically, I just print an UE4_log when I play the game.

I didn't get the "Compile Complete" notification and the log didn't show up at the output window.

And when I tried to build from Visual Studio, it will build the whole engine (like when you run the engine for the first time after pulling from Github).
I mean it is ridiculous to re-run the entire engine for each time I create a new C++ class from the editor.

Any idea what I've been missing or wrong?

Comment: There should be 2 projects in your solution: one is UE4 and one is your project. right-click on your project and select "Set as startup project" (or similar, not quite sure about the English version) or simply right-click on your project and select "Build project". EDIT sorry seems like I misunderstood your question. do you want to compile a class for UE4 or your own UE project?

Comment: On my own UE project. Not the engine's code itself. So, the "Compile Button" on the editor is not supposed to be working when we use the UE Editor from the Github version? Anyway, I tried your suggestion but, they still recompile the whole system. How about your Solution Configuration? There should be something different with my settings if yours able to compile only the project.

Comment: if the whole Engine code is being rebuilt then apparently the binary files for that are missing. if you have only checked out UE4.25 via Github and didn't compile yet then there won't be any pre-built binaries or libs inside the repo, you will have to rebuild all of it.

Answer (score 0):

if Unreal’s project have “git”, UE4 will try to use “git status” for detect changed file. This is a bug that made me compile unsuccessful. (I’m not sure but I think UE4 try to compile only changed file)

Solution

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/solved-i-cant-create-new-c-class/433056